# Auto Merging of two repository on daily basis

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Have 2 SVN repository one for check-in the code(**repo A**) and other repo(**repo B**) used for running the sonar. Is there a way to do auto merge for this 2 repository automatically on daily basis (i.e) from **repo A** to **repo B**?

*Note: I can't use same repo for both purpose due to some technical challenges.Need some suggestion on this*

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'auto-merge' and what exactly do you want to merge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a job for [`svnsync`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svnsync.html):

> `svnsync` is the Subversion remote repository mirroring tool. Put simply, it allows you to replay the revisions of one repository into another one.

Run this command once (with the right URLs):

```
svnsync initialize http://url.to.repo/B http://url.to.repo/A
```

Then set up a scheduled task to run a command like this:

```
svnsync synchronize http://url.to.repo/B
```